# UISliders and setting values

Tags: swift, uislider

I have a code I am writing and its going well but I am having trouble with UISliders...specifically...setting values. I have used the sliders and now I want to reset them to the original state (0 to 10 with a value of 0 and the slider all the way to the left. I have...

```
@IBOutlet weak var redHorizontalSlider: UISlider!
```

---

Inside viewDidLoad:

```
    redHorizontalSlider!.minimumValue = 0.0
    redHorizontalSlider!.maximumValue = 1.0
    redHorizontalSlider!.setValue(0.0, animated: false)
```

and when I print the values its giving me a nil and an error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

I have played around with ! and ?  in the declaration of the Object and the calls but to no avail.

Comment: Can you give more info about the error you're getting? Also, shouldn't your max value be 10?

Comment: sorry...I meant 1.0 in the first place.  Here is the error message I get when I try to set any of the values (max, min or set value)... fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: I used a ? and the errors went away but not the nil

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is going to happen because the value of your slider is nil. Check your connections to make sure that your storyboard slider is connected to the slider variable.